Executing queries on Postgres pool directly instead of fetching an idle instance
I'm trying to feather out some misunderstandings of how I've been querying with Postgres in my application.
Most of the documentation illustrates an approach like so:
const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: 'pooluser',
  host: 'localhost',
  // . . . other config
});

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
  console.log('error ', err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
  const instance = await pool.connect()
  const result = await instance.query('select ....');

  instance.release();

  pool.end();
});

So from what I gather, you connect to the pool to pluck out an instance, then you query with that instance and then release it (and, i guess, optionally, end the pool connection, which I reckon isn't common in a big application, because you'll always need the pool to be active).
Anyway, here's how I've been doing it:
const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: 'pooluser',
  host: 'localhost',
  // . . . other config
});

export const executeQuery = async ({ query }) => {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query(query, values)

        return result
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
  const result = await executeQuery({ query: 'select .....' })
  console.log('result', result.rows);
});

My question is the following. My approach has been working thus far. My concern is that I sometimes catch a "connection terminated unexpectedly" error and, therefore, I suspect that even though my approach works, it's not correct. Perhaps I get these crashes because I never release an instance? But this is what I don't understand, because instead of getting an instance, I just call query directly on Pool, which seems to be a valid use of their API, which is why I'm a little confused.
Am I incorrectly using Pool here? Do I actually need to connect first and then release an instance?
For more context, here's my Pool config:
{
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    max: 20,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 3e4,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: isDev ? 1e6 : 3e4,
    keepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelayMillis: isDev ? 1e6 : 3e4,
}

